# Item not found - Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome

Our company have a chrome extension with 50k users:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fbhbfmfbhlbhhjigoldgnibebpfobjpo

We are seeing an error "Item can't be found".

On developer page i see this:
Action needed!
At least one of your items has been removed from the store because it did not comply with our policies or terms of service.

We have filled all of the details, but we are not sure to what is the reason of the app being flagged.

Is there any support for Chrome web store? How can we figure this out?
The extension was live for over 6 mounts.

Comment: May I know your extension name please?

Comment: Kizi - Fun Free Games

Comment: Did you receive any email from google team justifying the action?

Comment: No. I only see "Action needed" on the developer page. We did not receive any email from Google explaining this issue

Comment: Checkout this long thread.. Might give some you some idea -> https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/2yTVWdfC4Gg

Comment: It's not the same issue... they are talking about chrome not allowing you to use an extension you already installed. Our extension was removed from the store